# php email, code reuse fails on second include

Tags: php

I posted earlier as an email and relocation issue, however after trying several things, and tracing (in production! yech!)
I have found the culprit - but have NO IDEA why or where to go from here.

you will see in the below code I include 'email.php' twice - because one receipt goes to the user, the other includes some meta data about the user and goes to support...

if i comment out the SECOND include, my redirect works, if i leave it in, it bombs...
the notify email is valid, and is the only thing that is different.

Im at a loss

PHP FORM PROCESSOR

```
...
// send two emails
    $_emailTo = $email; // the email of the person requesting
    $_emailBody = $text_body; // the stock response with things filled in
    include ( 'email.php' );

    $_emailTo = $notifyEmail; // the support email address
    $_emailBody = $pretext.$text_body; // pretext added as meta data for support w/ same txt sent to user
//I make it this far in my trace - then nothing 
     include ( 'email.php' );

// relocate
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=success.php" >';
    exit;
```

PHP MAILER (email.php)

```
<?php
    require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "mail.validmailserver.com";

//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 26;

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "validusername";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "pass1234";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->SetFrom('me@validmailserver.com', 'no-reply @ this domain');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@validmailserver.com','Support');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->AddAddress( $_emailTo );
$mail->Subject = $_emailSubject;
$mail->MsgHTML( $_emailBody );

$_emailError = false;

//Send the message, check for errors
if( !$mail -> Send() ) {
    $_emailError = true;
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
?>
```

help - please

Comment: its a class, include the file once, but initialise the class twice.

Comment: Yes, by including twice `email.php` you are requiring twice `class.phpmailer.php` which is a class definition. With PHP you cannot declare twice classes with the same name, it will give you an error.

Comment: You can use the `class_exists` to determine if you have to include the `class.phpmailer.php` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

It's the `require` in `email.php` that is causing the problems.  If you want to make the least change possible and make it work, change it to `require_once`.  This will ensure "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php" is only loaded once, therefore the class will only be defined once.

Answer (score 0):

take the `require()` line from email.php and put it in the calling file